# Rewrite rule for httpd.conf and virtual host SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have two virtual hosts in httpd.conf one for port 443 and one for port 80:

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:443>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to redirect every request to my server to go to `https://www.mysite.com/` except for `http://www.mysite.com/blog/` I want the blog to be non SSL. Where should I put RewriteRules, in which of the virtualHost directives? And what kind of rule do I need for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the port 80 VirtualHost, a rule will rewrite everything that isn't the blog to SSL.  In the 443 host, it will rewrite blog requests to non-ssl (if you want to force them back to non-ssl)

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Rewrite everything except the blog to SSL
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,QSA]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:443>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Rewrite the blog back to plain http
  # Leave this out if you don't care that https requests to the blog stay
  # on ssl
  RewriteRule ^(blog*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: In your 443 config, `RewriteRule ^(/blog/.*)  http://www.example.com$1 [L,R,QSA]` may be simpler. But that's nitpicking