# .htaccess rule not working for https

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

I write below htaccess rule in my hracess file. And its worked for http.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

But when i tried to access my site with HTTPS this rule is not execute. Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Note- I have installed SSL for my site.

Comment: show the section where you have added it to your config file, perhaps you nested it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a separate VirtualHost directive for ssl (port 443) in your httpd.conf file for apache, your existing rule isn't being evaluated due to it expecting port 80.

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491630/808532) as these lines to httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:443>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks for quick response. I added above code in httpd.con file but seems issue is not resolve. Any other solution?

Comment: Did you restart apache after making the change? Apache only reads the rules once at startup.

Comment: Yes. I restart the appache server.
http://educationchoices.com/degree-programs
https://educationchoices.com/degree-programs

Check above urls

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Your answer was correct. But the issue was i created two virtualhost for same 443 port. One of them having below code:

AllowOverride All
Allow from All

I just removed one VirtualHost and restart appache and my htaccess is start working. Thank for the support!!!!!